# How to specify name of program's config (appdata) folder?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, app-config

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2017 with an Installer project. I have some settings and custom files that the user should be able to change and keep when installing new versions, so I want to use the appdata folder for this.

The problem is that when I just use the default config files and `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`, it creates a folder in appdata with a very unwieldy name, like [Company]/[exe-name_Url_aBunchOfRandomLetters]/[Version number that isn't actually the version number I have specified in the installer project].
The random letters and version number make it seem like this path will change with new versions of the program, which it cannot do. And also I will need to access this folder to place other files than just the user.config file, so I would like the path to be more accessible and deterministic either way. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe look at _isolated storage_?

Comment: What if you check for the folder in AppData upon installation, if it doesn't exists, then create it again (which means the data is already lost, because it was deleted) or if it exists, don't copy the configuration file.

Comment: This is very much by design for the settings feature.  Microsoft was very panicky about programs overwriting each others user.config file by accident or the programmer modifying his program so it crashes on the old file content.  There are no knobs to change this behavior, beyond providing your own SettingsProvider implementation.  Not a lot of fun.  Google "localfilesettingsprovider alternative" to see if you like somebody else's solution.